Custom list in SharePoint On Premise Sites can be Export to Power BI site?
I created some custom lists in Team Site in SharePoint 2019 and created list items with custom columns, is this custom list can be possible to Export to Power BI site from custom list directly?

for any on-premises data like SharePoint, SQL server, etc., you will need to install and configure the Data Gateway. It's a free download in the Power BI Service.

